# Popup Login and Signup Form

Tags: jquery, css, forms, authentication, popup

Hi i have a popup login and signup form that is working almost good. The only problem in my popup is my popup is not scrolling down for bigger forms. also i am failed to stop scrolling of my backup container. This is my php

```
    <div class="container">
    <a class="modal_trigger btn" href=".modal"=>Click here to Login or register</a>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>

    <div class="modal popupContainer" style="display:none;">
        <header class="popupHeader">
            <span class="header_title">Login</span>
            <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </header>

        <section class="popupBody">
            <!-- Social Login -->
            <div class="social_login">
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#" class="social_box fb">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
                        <span class="icon_title">Connect with Facebook</span>

                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="social_box google">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="icon_title">Connect with Google</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="centeredText">
                    <span>Or use your Email address</span>
                </div>

                <div class="action_btns">
                    <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="login_form btn">Login</a></div>
                    <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="register_form btn">Sign up</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Username & Password Login form -->
            <div class="user_login">
                <form>
                    <label>Email / Username</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input class="remember" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="remember">Remember me on this computer</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="action_btns">
                        <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Login</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Register Form -->
            <div class="user_register">
                <form>
                    <label>Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input class="send_updates" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="send_updates">Send me occasional email updates</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="action_btns">
                        <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Register</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help ??

Complete working plugin link with Jquery Scripts, CSS, and HTML (jsfiddle) jsfiddle link is

http://jsfiddle.net/ashu398/gw4xrjtk/

Answer (score 1):

check final demo as required 
http://jsfiddle.net/gw4xrjtk/22/

```
(function($){$.fn.extend({leanModal:function(options){var defaults={top:100,overlay:0.5,closeButton:null};var overlay=$("<div class='lean_overlay'></div>");$("body").append(overlay);options=$.extend(defaults,options);return this.each(function(){var o=options;$(this).click(function(e){var modal_id=$(this).attr("href");$(".lean_overlay").click(function(){close_modal(modal_id)});$(o.closeButton).click(function(){close_modal(modal_id)});var modal_height=$(modal_id).outerHeight();var modal_width=$(modal_id).outerWidth();
$(".lean_overlay").css({"display":"block",opacity:0});$(".lean_overlay").fadeTo(200,o.overlay); $("body").css("overflow","hidden");$(modal_id).css({"display":"block","position":"fixed","opacity":0,"z-index":11000,"left":50+"%","margin-left":-(modal_width/2)+"px","top":o.top+"px"});$(modal_id).fadeTo(200,1);e.preventDefault()})});function close_modal(modal_id){$(".lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
```

Added overflow: hidden in line in

```
$(".lean_overlay").fadeTo(200,o.overlay); $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
```

and overflow : "auto" in

```
$(".lean_overlay").fadeOut(200); $("body").css("overflow","auto");
```

Comment: in this jsfiddle as soon as you open the modal you cannot scroll background. This is all you wanted right? and change top : 200 to top : 0

Comment: This works.. for the longer forms, you just need to make sure you have a height or max-height to .popupBody and your inner scroll will work.

Comment: @AshishGarg in your fiddle, your max-height is set to 'auto'.. change that to a fixed pixel amount.

Comment: @webkit u were right....after updating top-width as Dev said....max-height property for .popupBody started working.. Its working perfectly now..The only problem now is how i can stop scrolling background container... ??

Comment: update the working fiddle link that is ok for you till now so as can update in that fiddle

Comment: The thing is when u show popup call  $("body").css("overflow","hidden") and when you hide reset it with auto

Comment: @AshishGarg for you background to stop scrolling, you need to do what dev has suggested.. overflow your body to hidden when popup is active

Comment: @dev in your fiddle it is just removing scroll bar but the page is still scrolling using arrow keys..

Comment: For me its not scrolling. Dont know why it isnt working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope By using the following solves your problem

```
.popupContainer{
    position:absolute !important;
   }
```

Hope This sOlves your problem

Answer (score 0):

you have change minor css

```
.popupContainer {
position: absolute;
width: 330px;
height: auto;
left: 45%;
top: 20px;
background: #FFF;
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

may it help you